# SwiftUI: Why is my button not responding to a .keyboardShortcut modifier with KeyEquivalent?

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a button that should perform its action when the user presses the spacebar on the keyboard. Sounds simple, but the code below is not working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Quick Look") {
            print("pressed")
            //quickLookURL = ...
        }
        .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent.space)
    }
}
```

Interestingly it works if I use a [KeyboardShortcut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/keyboardshortcut):

```
 .keyboardShortcut(KeyboardShortcut(" ", modifiers: []))
```

Why is this?

Comment: I have run into the exact same issue without finding any solution or explanation so I just use `.keyboardShortcut(.space, modifiers: [])`. Hopefully this is something that gets improved in the future.

Comment: Really weird, I needed "delete", and it didn't work, but this does...

KeyboardShortcut(.delete, modifiers: []) 

Messed up.

Comment: I noticed when trying to use `.keyboardShortcut(.space)` on a `Button` inside a `.contextMenu`, the menu item showed the symbol for "command-space" instead of just "space" as the shortcut. This seems like a bug that is fixed when explicitly passing an empty set for the `.keyboardShortcut` modifiers parameter. This was on macOS Ventura 13.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
extension View {
    public func keyboardShortcut(_ key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers = .command) -> some View
    public func keyboardShortcut(_ shortcut: KeyboardShortcut) -> some View
}

public struct KeyboardShortcut : Sendable {
    public init(_ key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers = .command, localization: KeyboardShortcut.Localization)
}
```

modifiers of keyboardShortcut has a default value that is .command. init of KeyboardShortcut also has a default value that is .command too.

So, if you want no modifier you need to explicitly gives it an empty array, or it will take .command as default value.

Comment: good catch, thank you! makes sense.